# What is the correct sql query for this output?

Tags: sql-server

Table1

```
id    name    purchase   Group            
001   vince   26         G1                  
002   vince   28         G1                  
002   vince   31         G1                  
002   vince   38         G2
003   karl    24         G2
003   karl    24         G2
```

Expected Output

```
id    name     Purchase
001   vince    26
002   vince    59
003   karl     0
```

Comment: Is this some kind of riddle? Can you show what you have tried? Then we can help to fix that.

Comment: Hint: `SUM` and a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but here is a Query that should work:

```
 SELECT id, name, SUM(CASE WHEN [Group] = 'G1' THEN purchase ELSE 0 END) AS Purchase
 FROM Table1
 GROUP BY id, name
 ORDER BY id
```